# How do I redownload Ubuntu on my computer if Ubuntu will not load?

Tags: installation

My friend downloaded Ubuntu onto my laptop for me and when I restarted it after being asked for my password, it will not load past the boot options menu.
I do not have another computer to use and I am wondering if I can reload Ubuntu off of a passport or 7GB SD card.

Comment: I am not quite clear with your problem, give a short line please.

Comment: Why not use the live dvd/pendrive you used to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The Passport (TM) external hard drive would have to be created as a bootable hard drive for Linux, and Western Digital doesn't do that. You'd need a booting Linux computer to make the Passport bootable, and the process would erase the entire contents of that hard drive as it came formatted for NTFS instead.

Likewise, you would need a booting Linux computer to make that SD card bootable, and many laptops won't boot from an SD card.

Therefore, your best choice is to find a working Windows or Linux computer and with that, redownload the Ubuntu ISO file and apply that onto a USB Flash Drive ($10 or less at most supermarkets and department stores in the Anglosphere) or a CD-R disc (but in disc-at-a-time mode, not using either packet writing or track-at-a-time mode).